# Lightning Input fields

Tags: lightning-web-components

Can I create a lightning record form which is not related to any object it just checks the input values of the fields and posts the toast message.

Example

I want to create a quiz application wherein I have a country field and a capital field. So based on the conditions in the controller this form has to check and post the message. Like the country is Australia and in the controller I have an if condition which checks if the capital is canberra or not.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is entirely possible.
You can use 'lightning-input' tag to achieve this
Check details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/example)